# Reading JSON file with Python and printing a custom report

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON/CSV file as output from Watson TD, to keep track of the time I spend on learning different programming languages. Until now I load this data into Google sheets to produce something like this.

```
Fri 10-01-2021 09:30 - 11:30  =  2:00  Python  Learning about lists
Mon 10-04-2021 09:00 - 14:00  =  5:00  Python  Learning about dicts, Writing basic function
Tue 10-05-2021 09:00 - 14:00  =  5:00  Bash    Writing script to sort names, Testing script
Wed 10-06-2021 09:15 - 12:30  =  3:15  Python    
Wed 10-06-2021 13:30 - 14:00  =  0:30  Python  Reading about datatime module
Thu 10-07-2021 09:00 - 17:30  =  8:30  Python  Reading json files
Fri 10-08-2021 09:00 - 15:00  =  6:00  Bash    Practice with AWK
Mon 10-11-2021 09:00 - 15:30  =  6:30  Bash    Practice with scripts
Tue 10-12-2021 09:15 - 18:45  =  9:30  Python  Reading about doc strings
Total                         = 46:15
```

I would love to learn how to do this with Python. For now I'm stuck at loading the json file and printing the information within the file. I'm just starting to learn Python so any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#! /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

import json

with open("timesheet.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for hour in data:
    print(hour["id"], hour['project'], hour["start"], hour["stop"], hour["tags"])
```

JSON file generated by Watson [https://tailordev.github.io/Watson/]

```
[
    {
        "id": "4f82a4fd277843dc942c388657b38e85",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-01T09:30:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-01T11:30:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Learning about lists"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a1e7895f8ed141c883fe39f28f9bcfb2",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-04T09:00:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-04T14:00:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Learning about dicts",
            "Writing basic function"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ac8744d04c994120bde893bf6b1dbb7a",
        "project": "Bash",
        "start": "2021-10-05T09:00:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-05T14:00:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Writing script to sort names",
            "Testing script"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1d2eb32e7fdb41668ecbacfdacae62e4",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-06T09:15:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-06T12:30:00+02:00",
        "tags": []
    },
    {
        "id": "abb988019d5547919b73b4e3f61a82d6",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-06T13:30:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-06T14:00:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Reading about datatime module"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a348170f7e17425db5a6e75fbad2f31f",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-07T09:00:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-07T17:30:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Reading json files"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1f6b01d58a4c4b8687cb0e16d7ddedf2",
        "project": "Bash",
        "start": "2021-10-08T09:00:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-08T15:00:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Practice with AWK"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "170264e64d014d6caca4b510b3740420",
        "project": "Bash",
        "start": "2021-10-11T09:00:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-11T15:30:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Practice with scripts"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "7098d20f857943d7b624931f5a99b621",
        "project": "Python",
        "start": "2021-10-12T09:15:00+02:00",
        "stop": "2021-10-12T18:45:00+02:00",
        "tags": [
            "Reading about doc strings"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What exactly you try to do? The problem is not clear. Do you face any error?

Comment: I want to reproduce the output, that I know format manually, with Python. So I can print the information which is in the json file. But basically this is where I'm stuck. I know I have to convert the start and stop informatie to date objects. And I read about how to this for one single string. I'm breaking my head on how the best way to approach this.